# getview in listadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

In my listadapter code, I would like to indent my view. To do that i add some left padding but that doesnt seem to work.

**EDIT: main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/item_image" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

any suggestions why padding would not work ??   I want to move the image x dp to the right.

```
 @Override
        public final View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.main, null); 
                layout.setPadding(100, 8,8,8);


                return layout;
            } else {
//do stuff   
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: What's inside your main.xml file? You know padding doesn't change the position nor the size of the "box" it's being applied to, don't you? It applies to "internal margins" only, thus will appear only if main.xml contains other views.

Comment: Without you layout file we won't be able to help you

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
@Override
        public final View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


                final View layout = View.inflate(context, R.layout.main, null); 
                layout.setPadding(100, 8,8,8);


                return layout;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the reference of a xml file  ..... you should get reference to the layout defined in xml file or any other view of xml file to set params ......

You can set param on the view not on xml file....

Comment: He inflates a layout from the xml file that seems more or less correct to me

Answer (score 0):

If setting padding does not work, you could always try:

```
layout.offsetLeftAndRight(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess .. you can give padding in your xml layout using android:padding...... (left or right or top or bottom) . Specifying them in xml layout file will indent the ImageView as per requirements.

Comment: I want to change the indent depwnding on row values. Therefore cant specify it in xml